# Connection pooling is working?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, architecture

Recently , I see degradation of performnace of VB.NET windows application. Application is performing slow when users press the save button. Save button triggers several db calls to save several objects. We are planning to optimize this approach - like minimizing db calls etc. Before I jump and start minimizing db calls - my question here is , how can I know that connection polling is working? First, I am trying to see if conenction pooling is working at all or not. I am open to accept all suggestions to optimize this Save method. Please let me know if you need additional information.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the same connection string for each `SqlConnection` object then pooling is working. Remember this though, **do not share connections.**

Have a look at a post I made on my blog to show the [right way to use `SqlConnection` objects here](http://learncsharp.org/how-to-properly-and-safely-access-a-database-with-ado-net/).

Comment: Thanks ! Could you please explain a little what do you mean by "do not share connections."?

Comment: @user1630853, I mean when you need a connection, build it, open it, use it, and dispose it. The blog post states that at the end of the post. **Never** reuse a `SqlConnection` object.

Answer (score 1):

You should take care of the requirements of connection pooling, and SQL Server and ADO.NET would make it happen.

Essentially what you have to do is to:

1. Have one process
2. One application domain
3. One connection string
4. And one type of authentication

You can read more about it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca.aspx).

If you do these things, then everything should be OK.